# Is this SE being plagiarized?

Tags: discussion

From ping-backs, I noted:

- http://qandasys.info/how-can-i-tell-what-focal-length-a-zoom-lens-was-set-to-for-a-photo-of-the-moon/
- http://www.faceyoutub.com/photography/astrophotography-how-can-i-tell-what-focal-length-a-zoom-lens-was-set-to-for-a-photo-of-the-moon.html

both of which are exact copies of my SE posts (copied at different times), without illustrations, credited to "admin" with no acknowledgement as to the source.  They offer their own reply forms and feeds.

Do the owners of SE have a way to report this, and will they take action?

Answer (score 9):

Yep, looks bad. If the scraper site follows the Creative Commons BY-SA license, there's no problem (even though it's annoying when they do it with no meaningful value added). But when they don't even do that, Stack Exchange does take action.

Instructions for reporting these are here: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

Comment: The first link in the OP is reproducing without attribution... looks like [SE should be contacted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).